# best way to automatically send email monthly if certification is expired?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, windows-services

I have a webapp designed in asp.net mvc that sends emails via smtp no problem via on click event. But i need a way to automatically check every month for a certification if it is expired and email that user.  I am reading sql server or windows service. Which do you recommend and could you provide your link for me to read up on it. Thanks.

Comment: is the certification date stored in sql server? If so, set up a SQL job that checks the date of the certification and use sp_send_dbmail if it's expired. Just one of many ways.

Comment: or you can send the mail on the basis of certification date using window services. Follow the link below
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bba51c/create-windows-service-to-send-mail-daily-using-Asp-Net-and/

Answer (score 0):

Why bother? Sql Server doesn't care about the expiry date...

Joking aside, you'll probably notice that there are a number of internal certs that come with Sql Server that have expired. MS doesn't care about those but you should probably make sure you ignore them in any alert you receive.

You could use a policy (SSMS\Management\Policies) to alert you, something like:

```
Declare @object_set_id Int
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_object_set @object_set_name=N'Certs_ObjectSet', @facet=N'Certificate', @object_set_id=@object_set_id Output
Select @object_set_id

Declare @target_set_id Int
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set @object_set_name=N'Certs_ObjectSet', @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Certificate', @type=N'CERTIFICATE', @enabled=True, @target_set_id=@target_set_id Output
Select @target_set_id

Exec msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database/Certificate', @level_name=N'Certificate', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_target_set_level @target_set_id=@target_set_id, @type_skeleton=N'Server/Database', @level_name=N'Database', @condition_name=N'', @target_set_level_id=0


Go

Declare @policy_id Int
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_policy @name=N'Certs', @condition_name=N'Certs', @execution_mode=0, @policy_id=@policy_id Output, @object_set=N'Certs_ObjectSet'
Select @policy_id
```